# Powershell script takes long time with Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, task, scheduled-tasks

I have a really simple PS script. It ran instantly if I double click it or execute it through ISE, however on Windows startup (Task Scheduler) it takes almost half a minute

The script is to change Windows Background

```
    Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
namespace Wallpaper
{
   public enum Style : int
   {
       Tile, Center, Stretch, NoChange
   }
   public class Setter {
      public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
      public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
      public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;
      [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      private static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
      public static void SetWallpaper ( string path, Wallpaper.Style style ) {
         SystemParametersInfo( SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange );
         RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true);
         switch( style )
         {
            case Style.Stretch :
               key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "2") ; 
               key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ;
               break;
            case Style.Center :
               key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "1") ; 
               key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ; 
               break;
            case Style.Tile :
               key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "1") ; 
               key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "1") ;
               break;
            case Style.NoChange :
               break;
         }
         key.Close();
      }
   }
}
"@

[Wallpaper.Setter]::SetWallpaper( 'T:\WalllpBackground\harbinger2k914ktv.jpg', 2 )
```

I also exported the Task Scheduler as xml, changed the priority to 0 and 3 both with no luck (seems slow like 7 before)

The script indeed ran immediately on startup but it takes time to complete it (almost half a minute as stated)

Arguments: `-executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden T:\wallpchange.ps1`

Program/script: `powershell.exe`

It's kinda a bummer not to able to have background changed immediately so is there an alternative or a fix to my problem to speed things up?

Just need to change background through Task Scheduler where I can then define specific days where the wallpaper will be changed, right not it's on logon of any user to see if it's work

Also windows style hidden doesn't seem to hide my Powershell window too

I am using Windows 10 with PowerShell 5.0

It's also on SSD if that matters.

Comment: half a minute from when? how are you measuring this time?

Comment: By the time it changes from my old background that I had before to the new one

Comment: Maybe explorer isn't updating the view instantly? You can try to call a refresh of the desktop (I can't find the object where to do that right now though)

Comment: Windows Fast startup on seems to make it faster but not instantly. Here is what happens: PS window will run at startup for few seconds, then closes itself, then another few seconds the wallpaper will be changed